# Lex program to recognise valid arithmetic expression and also to recognise valid identifies and operators

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex, lexer

the below program checks the arithmatic expression like a+b a-b it gives the output valid or invalid;

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int c,d,bo=0,bc=0;
%}
operand [a-zA-Z0-9]+
operator [+\-\/*]
%%
//the operand is one count higher than the operator if that fails then its is invalid eg a+b operand is two and operator is 1;

{operator} {d++;printf("%s is an operator \n",yytext);} 

{operand} {c=d+1;printf("%s is an operand \n",yytext);}

"(" {if(bc<=bo)bo++;}

")" {bc++;}

\n {if(bo==bc&&c>d){printf("valid exp");}else {printf("invalid exp");};exit(0);}
%%
void main(){
yylex();
}
```

the problem that im am facing is when i check a++b it says valid but when i try a+b- and other values like )a+b(, (a+b(,+a-b++ it gives me right output .only for a++b and a--b or a+-b it fails.
Im kinda stuck.

this is the if condition for \n,I put it on \n bcz when I press enter it  gives me the output and exits.

```
if(bo==bc && c>d)                   //c>d means if operand is greater than operator
    {  printf("valid exp");  }
      else {  
             printf("invalid exp"); }
```

Comment: You'll need yacc to _parse_ expressions.

Comment: no expression doesnt matter its only checking if the given arithmatic expression is valid or not. And my constraint is lex only

Comment: You need to lookahead to differentiate `+` and `++`. Easy in yacc; don't know how to do that in lex.

Comment: but in the output it does say `+ is an operator` twice if input is `a++b`

Comment: ..and you don;t want that. You want to see "`++` is an operator". Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Anyway, lex can only identify lexical tokens. It cannot see context. So it would be right to identify "`+` is an operator" twice.

Comment: i do want that that is good , what i want is a++b should say invalid not valid exp.

Comment: even `-a` is showing valid

Answer (score 1):

i just changed c=d+1 to c++; it was a logical error that produced the error rather than checking for operand greater that operator i added 1 extra to operand and it always evaluated to true in a++b

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int c,d,bo=0,bc=0;
%}
operand [a-zA-Z0-9]+
operator [+\-\/*]
%%
//the operand is one count higher than the operator if that fails then its is invalid eg a+b operand is two and operator is 1;

{operator} {d++;printf("%s is an operator \n",yytext);} 

{operand} {c++;printf("%s is an operand \n",yytext);}

"(" {if(bc<=bo)bo++;}

")" {bc++;}

\n {if(bo==bc&&c>d){printf("valid exp");}else {printf("invalid exp");};exit(0);}
%%
void main(){
yylex();
}
```